# How to calculate Savitzky Golay Smoothing Filter - Filtering efficiency matlab?

Tags: matlab, filtering

Dear Stackoverflow members,
I am newbie in signal processing, so plz help. :).
As in the title, how to calculate the Savitzky Golay Smoothing Filter's efficiency? And which information should I provide to you?
I am using sgolayfilt, 3rd order, window size of 13 (MATLAB 2014a), the signal and filtered one are in the figure.
Thanks all!
[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you said "filtering efficiency" ?

Comment: I mean how much noise was removed, the signal distortion and the cost.

Comment: Do you know the answer?